# AS3 Video & NetStream : MP4 video not showing with appendBytes

Tags: actionscript-3, video, mp4

I'm trying to stream some MP4 video in a Video component in an Air application, using a NetStream and the netStream.appendBytes method. The source video is coming from a socket so I need to append the Bytes, but it was not working. So I tried to appendBytes from a file read from the system, it still wasn's working. I tried putting that file as the source of a VideoPlayer element, and it did work.

I then tried the appendBytes method to open an flv file from the system and it did work, so I knew I was not doing something wrong in my process. What does VideoPlayer do that I don't when I use the appendBytes method, that would make it work like I want ?

Answer (score 1):

[You cannot use appendBytes and mp4 containers](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4008099).  AppendBytes works with FLV frames only.

Comment: Indeed :( And from the topic you linked, it seems changing the header does not work (or I just don't do it the right way) Is there a way to convert on the fly my MP4 stream to an FLV stream ?

Comment: That's really complicated.  The mp4 container is MUCH MUCH MUCH MUCH MUCH more difficult to parse/read -- and then you'd have to decode/encode -- which is a bit much cpu-wise.  The FLV spec is so much more simple to parse and use appendbytes ...  I would suggest encoding your videos that way if at all possible.

Comment: I can't, I'm receiving MP4 on my socket :(